# Find the max value across all features in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Consider the following code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_slice=3
labels_slice=2

def split_window(x):  
    inputs = tf.slice(x,[0], [input_slice])
    labels = tf.slice(x,[input_slice], [labels_slice]) 
    return inputs, labels

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 25 + 1).batch(5).map(split_window)

for i, j in dataset:
    print(i.numpy(),end="->")
    print(j.numpy())
```

This code will give me the output:

```
[1 2 3]->[4 5]
[6 7 8]->[ 9 10]
[11 12 13]->[14 15]
[16 17 18]->[19 20]
[21 22 23]->[24 25]
```

Every row in the tensor `j` represents a feature. I want to find the max value across all features. In this case, it would be 25. How would I find the max value across all features?

Comment: freak11, I have removed your [[tag:batch-file]] tag. What you've submitted does not mention, or imply a Windows Batch File, with a `.bat` extension, or a Windows Command Script, with a `.cmd` extension. Please check the information for your tags, before assigning them, and if you feel they are relevant, please make sure that your question content sufficiently backs up their use. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to your problem would be to use `tf.TensorArray` and `tf.reduce_max`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_slice=3
labels_slice=2

def split_window(x):  
    inputs = tf.slice(x,[0], [input_slice])
    labels = tf.slice(x,[input_slice], [labels_slice]) 
    return inputs, labels

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 25 + 1).batch(5).map(split_window)

ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.int64, size=0, dynamic_size=True)

for i, j in dataset:
    print(i.shape, i.numpy(),end="->")
    print(j.numpy())
    ta.write(ta.size(), j)
    
max_value = tf.reduce_max(ta.stack(), axis=(0, 1)).numpy()

print(max_value)
# 25
```

With `tf.reduce_max` you are getting the max value across the dimensions 0 and 1 and reducing your tensor. Feel free to give some feedback, if I did not understand the question correctly.